# Generic producer and consumer

Tags: java, generics

I'm designing a container class which is intended to hold pair of implementations of

```
public interface MetaData<ValueType>{
    public String getName();
}
```

and the corresponding value of the `ValueType` Type parameter. So I've written this (*enforcing of some invariants ommited*):

```
public final class ParametersImpl implements Parameters{

    private final Map<MetaData<?>, Object> parameters;
    {
        parameters = new HashMap<>();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValue(MetaData<?> pmd) {
        return parameters.get(pmd);
    }

    @Override
    public <M> void put(MetaData<M> p, M value) {
        parameters.put(p, value);
    }
}
```

where

```
public interface Parameters {

    public Object getValue(MetaData<?> pmd);
    public <M> void put(MetaData<M> p, M value);
}
```

The thing is when a client calls method `Object getValue(MetaData<?> pmd)` they have to do explicit cast:

```
MetaData<List<Integer>> metaData;
Paramters params;
List<Integer> list= new ArrayList<>();
//intialization
params.put(metaData, list);
//do some other
List<Integer> lst = (List<Integer>) params.getValue(metaData);
```

Although the cast is completely safe, I'd like to avoid it and provide some kind of generic method. But when I try this declaration:

```
public <M> M getValue(MetaData<M> pmd);
```

I got a compile-error in the implementation:

```
public <M> M getValue(MetaData<M> pmd) {
    return parameters.get(pmd); //cannot convert capture-of-#1 to M
}
```

***QUESTION:*** Is there a way to generify the method `public Object getValue(MetaData<?> pmd);` in any way?

Comment: Your hashmap is declared to have value-type `Object`. Presumably that should be some generic type ...?

Comment: Could you do a cast inside `getValue`?

Comment: Simply cast: `return (M) parameters.get(pmd)` and annotate the method with `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`

Comment: @Raffaele Damn, it's as simply as genius. Thanks much.

Comment: Can't you use `Parameters<M>` and `getValue(MetaData<M> pmd)`

Comment: @RC. I don't think that `Parameters<M>` has a lot of sense because the `Parameters` is intended to hold values of different types, not just `M`.

Comment: I'd like to hear the reasoning behind this sort of half-typed design. I'd also suggest avoiding instantiating variables like you're doing with `parameters`. It looks like it's an anonymous class, when it's just an unnecessary initialization block.

Comment: @Kayaman _I'd like to hear the reasoning behind this sort of half-typed design_ To execute sql-query I have to construct it first. For the construction I need some set of params of completely different types (e.g. `List<T>`, `Integer`, `String`, `Map<M, T>`, `Date`, etc). So I need in some type-safe container. That's why I provide such type-safety in that way. The `MetaData<T>` objects enforcing type-safety via the generic method. Doesn't it look like overkill?

Comment: Ah, now the question (and the answer) makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to cast the value retrieved from the map:

```
public <M> M getValue(MetaData<M> pmd) {
  return (M) parameters.get(pmd);
}
```

But at this point the compiler complains that it can't check the cast. What does it mean? Well, a *normal* cast in Java source code is expressed with `(SomeType) val` -  the compiler checks that the operation is not completely illegal (for example you can't cast a `String` reference to an `Integer`) and emits a bytecode that is executed at runtime, when it may throw a `ClassCastException`.

When you cast a reference with a type variable, the compiler **can't emit** such a bytecode because the type variable does not exist at runtime - so a compilation warning is issued instead. You should:

- ensure that the map is populated with the right values
- suppress the warning with `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`